# Error hiding an iframe from a label inside it

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I have an iframe in my page, and i need to open it and close it, which seems easy enough. I made a js file containing the functions needed for it, it looks like this:

**Script.js**

```
// Show About
function exibirAbout(){
    document.getElementById('AboutFrame').style.display = 'block';
}

//Hide About    
function ocultarAbout(){
    document.getElementById('AboutFrame').style.display = 'none';
}
```

It simply changes the property style of my iframe from block to none, pretty simple. However, i've been getting an "Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property style of null" On the hide function. This is the iframe and the button that shows it:

**Main.php**

```
                                </iframe>


                                <input type="submit" class="submit" onclick="exibirAbout();" value="About"/>
```

And here's the code for the function on the iframe, that hides it:

**About.php**

```
  <a onclick="ocultarAbout();">
    <label style='color: red; position: absolute; right: 6px; top: 5px; cursor: pointer;'>
        Close
    </label>
</a>
```

Usually this error has to do with the order the function has been declared, but due to it being on separate files, i'm not sure if that's the case. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

To do it in a clean way, you should wrap your iframe in a div, with id "AboutFrame":

```
<div id="AboutFrame">
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```